# Manipulating data with string titles

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering

I have a sales data, the data has columns including

```
sales_2000, sales_2001, sales_2002...sales_2020
```

I am trying to extract rows that have following features:

1. first 8 years have zero value
2. On the 9th year, it has value larger than 0.

Any suggestions on how to code this using pandas?

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 0):

I have simplified this problem for my answer because I didn't want to do that much typing. In the future, please provide actual sample data and any code you may have already tried in order to solve this problem. That being said, here is how you could find rows that have the first two years equal to `0` and the third greater than using slices:

**In:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    sales_2000 = [1,0,10,0,5,0], 
    sales_2001 = [2,0,8,1,0,0], 
    sales_2002 = [1,2,3,0,0,4],
))
print(f'Orignal DataFrame:\n{df}')

df_extracted = df[
    (
        df['sales_2000'] == 0
    ) & (
        df['sales_2001'] == 0
    ) & (
        df['sales_2002'] > 0
    )
]
print(f'\nExtracted DataFrame:\n{df_extracted}')
```

**Out:**

```
Orignal DataFrame:
   sales_2000  sales_2001  sales_2002
0           1           2           1
1           0           0           2
2          10           8           3
3           0           1           0
4           5           0           0
5           0           0           4

Extracted DataFrame:
   sales_2000  sales_2001  sales_2002
1           0           0           2
5           0           0           4
```

The key here is to wrap each condition inside of Round brackets `(condition)` and use the `&` operator to combine each condition. The `and` key word will not work here. [Python Tutor Link to Example Code](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28dict%28%0A%20%20%20%20sales_2000%20%3D%20%5B1,0,10,0,5,0%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20sales_2001%20%3D%20%5B2,0,8,1,0,0%5D,%20%0A%20%20%20%20sales_2002%20%3D%20%5B1,2,3,0,0,4%5D,%0A%29%29%0Aprint%28f'Orignal%20DataFrame%3A%5Cn%7Bdf%7D'%29%0A%0Adf_extracted%20%3D%20df%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'sales_2000'%5D%20%3D%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20%29%20%26%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'sales_2001'%5D%20%3D%3D%200%0A%20%20%20%20%29%20%26%20%28%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20df%5B'sales_2002'%5D%20%3E%200%0A%20%20%20%20%29%0A%5D%0Aprint%28f'%5CnExtracted%20DataFrame%3A%5Cn%7Bdf_extracted%7D'%29%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=6&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)